# Warning messages when I've updated the cn1 library

Tags: codenameone

Why does the following msg is seen in the output?

[EDT] 0:0:0,35 - WARNING: Theme sets the commandBehavior constant which is deprecated.  Please update the theme to NOT include this theme constant.  Using commandBehavior may cause your app to perform in unexpected ways.  In particular, using SIDE command behavior in conjunction with Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(true) may result in runtime exceptions.
[EDT] 0:0:0,36 - WARNING: Display.setCommandBehavior() is deprecated, Using it may result in unexpected behaviour. In particular, using COMMAND_BEHAVIOR_SIDE_NAVIGATION in conjunction with Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(true) may result in runtime errors.

P.S I've already updated the cn1 library and it gives "your project libs are up to date" when I click  properties > update project libs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says:

> Theme sets the commandBehavior constant which is deprecated. Please
>   update the theme to NOT include this theme constant. Using
>   commandBehavior may cause your app to perform in unexpected ways. In
>   particular, using SIDE command behavior in conjunction with
>   Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(true) may result in runtime exceptions

Which means either:

- Invoke `Toolbar.setOnTopSideMenu(false)` in your `init(Object)` method
- Open the theme and remove the `commandBehavior` entry from the theme constants